# Why won't the total calculate after adding a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am practicing javascript.
When I add an additional function the total won't calculate.

This is my javascript code where I wrote functions and my HTML code where it perform the total.

My html code contains one text input & two select elements to enter values. After that it displays the total in realtime.

```js
var cpaper_wt = new Array();

cpaper_wt["60"] = 200;
cpaper_wt["70"] = 5;
cpaper_wt["80"] = 5;
cpaper_wt["90"] = 7;
cpaper_wt["100"] = 8;
cpaper_wt["110"] = 10;
cpaper_wt["120"] = 5;
cpaper_wt["130"] = 9;
cpaper_wt["150"] = 5;
cpaper_wt["170"] = 5;
cpaper_wt["180"] = 8;
cpaper_wt["200"] = 1000;
cpaper_wt["240"] = 12;
cpaper_wt["250"] = 12;
cpaper_wt["300"] = 12;



function getcpwt() {
  var cpwt = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["parameterForm"];
  var selectedcpwt = theForm.elements["c_paper_weight"];

  cpwt = cpaper_wt[selectedcpwt.value];

  return cpwt;
}




var ipaper_wt = new Array();

ipaper_wt["60"] = 100;
ipaper_wt["70"] = 5;
ipaper_wt["80"] = 5;
ipaper_wt["90"] = 7;
ipaper_wt["100"] = 8;
ipaper_wt["110"] = 10;
ipaper_wt["120"] = 5;
ipaper_wt["130"] = 9;
ipaper_wt["150"] = 5;
ipaper_wt["170"] = 5;
ipaper_wt["180"] = 8;
ipaper_wt["200"] = 7;
ipaper_wt["240"] = 12;
ipaper_wt["250"] = 12;
ipaper_wt["300"] = 12;



function getipwt() {
  var ipwt = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["parameterForm"];
  var selectedipwt = theForm.elements["ip_paper_weight"];

  ipwt = ipaper_wt[selectedipwt.value];

  return ipwt;
}

//Cover Product Color
var cpc = new Array();

cpc["10"] = 100;
cpc["20"] = 500;
cpc["30"] = 550;
cpc["40"] = 700;




function getcpc() {
  var cover_pc = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["parameterForm"];
  var selectedcover_pc = theForm.elements["c_product_color"];

  cover_pc = cpc[selectedcover_pc.value];

  return cover_pc;
}





//No of inner pages

function nofip() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("inner").value);

  return x;
}



function calculateTotal() {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var base_price = 600 + getipwt() + getcpwt() + getcpc();
  var BPrice = base_price + nofip();

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price is $" + BPrice;

}




function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body onload="hideTotal()">
  <!--<div id="wrap">-->
  <form action="" id="parameterForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>
      <div class="cont_order">
        <fieldset>
          <select onchange="calculateTotal()" name="c_paper_weight" id="c_paper_weight" required>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="60">60 GSM</option>
            <option value="70">70 GSM</option>
            <option value="80">80 GSM</option>
            <option value="90">90 GSM</option>
            <option value="100">100 GSM</option>
            <option value="110">110 GSM</option>
            <option value="120">120 GSM</option>
            <option value="130">130 GSM</option>
            <option value="150">150 GSM</option>
            <option value="170">170 GSM</option>
            <option value="180">180 GSM</option>
            <option value="200">200 GSM</option>
            <option value="240">240 GSM</option>
            <option value="250">250 GSM</option>
            <option value="300">300 GSM</option>
          </select>

          <select name="ip_paper_weight" id="ip_paper_weight" required onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="60">60 GSM</option>
            <option value="70">70 GSM</option>
            <option value="80">80 GSM</option>
            <option value="90">90 GSM</option>
            <option value="100">100 GSM</option>
            <option value="110">110 GSM</option>
            <option value="120">120 GSM</option>
            <option value="130">130 GSM</option>
            <option value="150">150 GSM</option>
            <option value="170">170 GSM</option>
            <option value="180">180 GSM</option>
            <option value="200">200 GSM</option>
            <option value="240">240 GSM</option>
            <option value="250">250 GSM</option>
            <option value="300">300 GSM</option>
          </select>

          <label>Inner Pages</label>
          <input name="inner_pages" type="number" id="inner" value="0" placeholder="Inner pages." oninput="calculateTotal()">


          <label>Cover Product Color</label>
          <select name="c_product_color" id="c_product_color" required onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Single Color</option>
            <option value="2">Two Colors</option>
            <option value="3">Three Colors</option>
            <option value="4">Multi Colors</option>
          </select>

          <div id="totalPrice"></div>

        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!--</div>End of wrap-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Side-note: if you intend to use random properties that do not follow the order of natural numbers, it's recommended to use objects instead of arrays: `let x = {}; x[60] = 200;` and so on, instead of declaring `x` as new Array.

Comment: Which "additional function" did you add, where did you add it and what exactly is the problem with the "total" afterwards (errors, empty , ..)

Comment: It is hard to see what's going wrong. Do you see any errors on the browser console after you add a new function and the calculation of the total wouldn't work as expected? If so, please add the output on the browser console to your question, along with the other function that causes it.

Comment: if i remove the getcpc() function from the calculateTotal() function

Comment: sry for that ....if i remove the getcpc() function from the calculateTotal() function  var base_price = 600 + getipwt() + getcpwt() + getcpc();
    var BPrice = base_price + nofip() ;

Comment: it runs perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
`cover_pc = cpc[selectedcover_pc.value];`

For whatever reason your `cpc` array is indexed in increments of ten, so you can fix this by changing that line to:

`cover_pc = cpc[selectedcover_pc.value*10];`

Comment: the same increment is for ipwt = ipaper_wt[selectedipwt.value]; it runs perfectly.....

Comment: This is because the value of `selectedipwt` increments in values of 10 (60,70,80 etc.) but the value of selectedcover_pc can be either 1,2,3, or 4. You can also fix this problem by changing the values to 10,20,30, and 40 in the html instead of changing the javascript